# Magento 2 - Moving Category Listing Toolbar

Tags: magento2, category, layout, xml

I'm trying to move the category page's toolbar above the left and right column in the 2columns-left layout so it spans over both the left column and right column, but nothing seems to be working.

In my theme's `catalog_category_view.xml` I have the following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="columns" before="div.sidebar.main" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it. This feature of the system... see [my question](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7253) in github issues.

Answer (score 1):

The tool bar in M2 is a little convoluted. Take a look at this article, it will tell you why.

http://alanstorm.com/why-you-cant-remove-the-productlisttoolbar/